# Which of the following statements are true regarding ' sup norm' topology

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Consider the space $X=C[0,1]$ with its usual 'sup-norm' topology 
Let $$S=\{f\epsilon X| \int_{0}^1f(t)dt=0\}$$
Which of the following statements are true ?

1. The set S is closed
2. The set S is connected
3. The set S is compact

Here $X=C[0,1]$ is the space of continuous real valued functions on an interval [0,1] and is endowed with the 'sup-norm' topology.

Try- The set is closed

Consider the function $\phi:X\rightarrow R$ Here R is the set of real numbers I will prove that the function $\phi$ defined as $\phi(f)=\int_{0}^1 f(t)dt$ is in fact continuous 
$$\vert\phi f-\phi g\vert \le \vert\int_{0}^1f(t)dt-\int_{0}^1g(t)dt\vert\le\int_{0}^1\vert f(t)-g(t)\vert dt \; \forall \;\epsilon [0,1] \le $$

$$sup\vert f(t)-g(t)\vert \; \forall \; \epsilon [0,1] \le \epsilon $$ $$ for \;f \; and \;g \; \epsilon X$$
hence $\phi$ is continuous therefore $f^{-1}(0)$ is closed But it is given answer is 1 and 2 Why 2 ? What about 3

Comment: For connectedness, first examine path-connectedness, which is usually easier to handle; then if that fails you can always tackle the harder problem. For compactness, maybe consider whether $E = \{f\in C[0,0.5]: f(0.5)=0\}$ is compact with that norm, as an isometry into $S$ can readily be found.

Answer (score 1):

For the path-connexity, consider two functions $f$ and $g$ in $E$. For $t\in[0,1]$, consider $\phi_t:x\mapsto (1-t)f(t)+tg(t)$.

The map $t\mapsto \phi_t$ is a continuous path from $f$ to $g$, which bears entirely in $E$, for
$$(\forall t\in[0,1])\,\int_0^1 \phi_t(u)\,{\rm d}u = (1-t)\int_0^1 f(u)\,{\rm d}u + t\int_0^1 g(u)\,{\rm d}u=0$$